# How to check dataset for typos and replace them?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, unique

I have a question.
Is there a way on how to check wheteher there are typos in a specific column?
I have an Excel sheet which is read by use of pandas.

First I need to make a unique list in Python, based on the name of the column;
Second I need to replace the wrong values with the new values.

Comment: What do you mean by typos? As in misspelled words?

Comment: The data has multipe values in column 'Region' 
Midwest 
Northwest 
West 
Northeast 
East coast 
Central 
South 
International 
Centrall Typo => needs to be changed
Soouth Typo => needs to be changed

Comment: There's not really a simple way to do that. I guess you could try to make some kind of pattern matching algorithm to identify terms that don't fit your normal criteria but that wouldn't be easy. You can have a look at [this](https://pyspellchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and see if it matches your use

Comment: Is there a way to use group_by and after that finding and replacing the values in the file?

Comment: You can certainly find rows with values that aren't in your list, but it's very difficult for the computer to figure out what the value was intended to be.  Much easier to present them to a user for manual correction.

Answer (score 0):

Working in a Jupyter notebook and doing this semi-manually might be the best way. One option could be to start by creating a list of correct spelling:

```
correct= ['terms','that','are','spelt','correctly']
```

and create a subset from your data frame which does not contain the values in that list.

```
df[~df['columnname'].str.startswith(tuple(correct))]
```

You will then know how many rows are affected. You can then count the number of different variations:

```
df['columnname'].value_counts()
```

and if reasonable, you could look at the unique values, and make them into a list:

```
listoftypos = list(df['columnname'].unique())
print(listoftypos)
```

and then create a dictionary again in a semi-manual way as:

```
typodict= {'terma':'term','thaaat':'that','arree':'are','speelt':'spelt','cooorrectly':'correct'}
```

then iterate over your original data frame, and if a row in the column contains the keyword which is in your list of typos, then replace it with the correct key from the dictionary, something like this:

```
for index,row in df.itterows():
    if any(row['columnname'] in s for s in listoftypos):
        correctspelling = list(typodict.keys())[list(typodict.values()).index(row['columnname'])]) 
    df.at[index,'columnname'] = correctspelling
```

A strong caveat here though - of course, this would be something that would have to be done iteratively if the dataframe was extremely large.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a generic spell check is a fairly tall order, but I believe this solution will fit your need with the lowest chance of false matches:

**Setup:**

```
import difflib
import re
from itertools import permutations

cardinal_directions=['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
regions=['coast', 'central', 'international', 'mid']

p_lst=list(permutations(cardinal_directions+regions,2)) 
area=[''.join(i) for i in p_lst]+cardinal_directions+regions

df=pd.DataFrame({"ID":list(range(0,9)), "region":['Midwest', 'Northwest', 'West', 'Northeast', 'East coast', 'Central', 'South', 'International', 'Centrall']})
```

**Initial DF:**

| ID | region |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Midwest |
| 1 | Northwest |
| 2 | West |
| 3 | Northeast |
| 4 | East coast |
| 5 | Central |
| 6 | South |
| 7 | International |
| 8 | Centrall |

**Function:**

```
def spell_check(my_str, name_bank):
    prcnt=[]
    for y in name_bank:
        prcnt.append(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, y, my_str.lower().strip()).ratio())
    return name_bank[prcnt.index(max(prcnt))]
```

**Apply Function to DF:**

```
df.region=df.region.apply(lambda x: spell_check(x, area))
```

**Resultant DF:**

| ID | region |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | midwest |
| 1 | northwest |
| 2 | west |
| 3 | northeast |
| 4 | eastcoast |
| 5 | central |
| 6 | south |
| 7 | international |
| 8 | central |

---

I hope this answers your question and good luck.